# What is the event called for Cheque received and cheque cleared?

Tags: magento2

In admin

Sales->Orders->Cheque Received->Notify customer by Email

I want to know either which event is called or which template is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per I know there is no such an event for `checkmo` payment method that's why It calls the `offline` payment method. You need to do some manual operation for that. For more reference, you can check the model of this payment method which extends

`Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod` from this [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/OfflinePayments/Model/Checkmo.php#L16)